# Better perfomance with setInterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a react app. I have a TimeZone page. The problem is, there's currently 12 different timezones, and to display a ticking clock, I use the setInterval function, with 1000 ms delay for eachone. The problem is, sometimes the page freezes, and the clock jump the seconds it froze. I was wondering if there's a better way to do it.

I tried hard coding it all, but it took too many lines, the timezones comes with a json, and I call a function to build each individual clock. In this case 12 times.

```
   criaRelogio = (city, flag, locale) =>{
        setInterval( () => this.setState({
                 data: new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: locale}),
            }),
           1000
        );

        moment.updateLocale('en', {
            weekdays : [
                "Dom", "Seg", "Ter", "Qua", "Qui", "Sex", "Sab"
            ]
        });

        let data = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: locale});

        let dataCompleta = moment(data);
        let hora = dataCompleta.hour();
        let minutos = dataCompleta.minutes();
        let segundos = dataCompleta.seconds();
        let diaExtenso = dataCompleta.format("dddd");

        if(hora < 10){
           hora = "0" + hora;
        }

        if(minutos < 10){
            minutos = "0" + minutos;
        }

        if(segundos < 10){
            segundos = "0" + segundos;
        }

        let classe = "timezone-clock"
        if(hora > 18 || hora < 6 ){
            classe = "timezone-clock noite";
        }
        let resultado = diaExtenso + " " +  hora + ":" + minutos + ":" + segundos;

        let retorno = <div>
                        <Clock
                            value={new Date(data)}
                            renderNumbers={true}
                            renderMinuteMarks={false}
                            renderHourMarks={true}
                            hourMarksWidth={0}
                            hourHandWidth={2}
                            minuteHandWidth={2}
                            minuteHandLength={80}
                            secondHandLength={80}
                            className={classe}
                        />
                        <article>
                                <img src={require('../../Images/'+flag+".png")} alt="BR"/><strong>{city}</strong>

                                <br></br>
                                {resultado}
                        </article>
                    </div> 
        return retorno;
    }
```

I expect the freezing to subside and the page run more faster and smoothly.

Comment: is it normal that you don't define any delay in your setInterval call ?

Comment: Um, you're not passing any interval time to your `setInterval` call?

Comment: Where and how often do you call `criaRelogio`?

Comment: in the Render function, using the array.map function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using requestAnimationFrame in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52212703/using-requestanimationframe-in-react)